# Mysql - Query DATETIME field (indexed) performance

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, indexing

In my database, there is table called `Profile` which has a `DATETIME` field called `birthday`.

I want to query all the records that has birthday between **05-24** and **06-07** (`mm-dd`) regardless of what year it is and I used the following query:

```
DATE_FORMAT(`Profile`.`birthday`, "%m-%d") >= '05-24' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(`Profile`.`birthday`, "%m-%d") <  '06-07'
```

The problem is by doing this way, the **index** on `birthday` column has **no use**, the query is too slow and I want to improve the speed of my query

Please show me if there is any workaround that could still do the job and improve the query performance at the same time

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? 5.7 allows indexing of "virtual columns"

Comment: i'm using mysql 5.6, you can show me another solution

Comment: its a good idea to use virtual columns. use virtual persitent column, so you can also use a index on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

the reason is that you use a FUNCTION on a field in WHERE. This means that MySQL must read all Records of the Table (FULL TABLE SCAN).

You can add a new field birthday2 where you store only day and month with a normalized year like

```
UPDATE yourTable set birthday2 = DATE_FORMAT(Profile.birthday, "%m-%d-0001");
```

Ten you can select like

```
SELECT * from yourTable
WHERE birthday2 BETWEEN ''05-24-0001' AND '06-07-001';
```

And if you set a index on this field it will be used

Comment: Hi @Bernd Buffen, i have problem when using between. 
**explain (SELECT * from profiles
WHERE birthday2 BETWEEN '0001-01-01' AND '0001-03-06' )** it using **index condition**. But **explain (SELECT * from profiles
WHERE birthday2 BETWEEN '0001-01-01' AND '0001-06-06' )**  Using where.

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: Here is image my screen. [link](http://prnt.sc/b91aw7) and [link](http://prnt.sc/b91ben). If you require any further information, contact me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add another column

```
mmdd CHAR(5) CHARACTER SET ascii
and
INDEX(mmdd)
```

Set it using an `UPDATE` with `SET mmdd = DATE_FORMAT(..., "%m-%d")`

As a string (`CHAR`), it would compare 'correctly' unless you wrap around a year boundary (eg, November to February).

For 5.6 -- do it explicity.
For 5.7 or MariaDB -- use virtual column.

Keep in mind that if your date range is "too big" (somewhere around 2 months), the optimizer will ignore the index and do a full table scan.  This is deliberate, and actually optimal.